# python3 error, cannot import name 'SimpleQueue'

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

import asyncio, os, json, time
from datetime import datetime

from aiohttp import web

def index(request):
    return web.Response(body=b'<h1>Awesome</h1>')

@asyncio.coroutine
def init(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', index)
    srv = yield from loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '127.0.0.1', 9000)
    logging.info('server started at http://127.0.0.1:9000...')
    return srv

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

> Process (28411) start...
>   I (28411) just created a child process (28412).
>   I am child process (28412) and my parent is 28411.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "webApp.py", line 5, in 
>       import asyncio, os, json, time
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "webApp.py", line 5, in 
>       import asyncio, os, json, time
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>       from .base_events import *
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in 
>       from .base_events import *
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in 
>       import concurrent.futures
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/**init**.py", line 17, in 
>       import concurrent.futures
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/**init**.py", line 17, in 
>       from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 54, in 
>       from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 54, in 
>       from multiprocessing import SimpleQueue
>       from multiprocessing import SimpleQueue
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleQueue'
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleQueue'

Comment: Can you import the multiprocessing library alone ? Can you run `python3 -c "from multiprocessing import SimpleQueue"` for instance ?

Comment: I can import the multiprocessing library alone, but I can't  run python3 -c "from multiprocessing import SimpleQueue".

Answer (score 3):

The API for simpleQueue seems to have changed.

In python3.3, it is found in `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` (see the doc [1](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.SimpleQueue))

In python3.2, it is found in `multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue` (see the doc [2](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue))

You probably run a version of python older than 3.2 but the code was written for a newer version (>= 3.3). You can try to modify the library to use the old import or upgrade your python version.

Comment: I was thinking it was under the module: `queue` so i could do: `from queue import SimpleQueue` but it seems that yes, in later versions of python, the SimpleQueue class has indeed been moved.